# Codimension of the non-locally free locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a Noetherian, integral scheme. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a torsion free sheaf on $X$ and let $U \subseteq X$ be the open subscheme where $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free.

> **Q.** Is it true that $\mathrm{codim}_X(X\setminus U)\geq 2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, assuming $X$ to be *normal*.

See S. Ishii, *Introduction to singularities* ([Zbl 1308.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1308.14001)), Proposition 5.1.7 p. 83.